# How can socket Server catch data from client just in the moment when client send it?

Tags: java, android, client, byte, send

The program consist that I have to send a byte from by Android app to a Wifi Access Point, then this byte is interpreted by a hardware device.

I can send byte to client and it receives the byte correctly (and more bytes, don't know why, maybe because protocol). Hardware filter protocol bytes and catch only the correct one.

There's is how i send it (byte es created previously in another method, but it's correct):

```
public static void sendByte (Byte data) throws IOException { 

    DataOutputStream output; 
    Socket client; 
    client = new Socket("1.2.3.4", 2000); 
    output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    output.write(data); 
    output.close(); 
    client.close(); 
    Log.w("INFO","Data sended");

}
```

When I send the byte, hardware part change the color of a light, and it happens successfully.

I putted this 3 lines too:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Until here there's no problem.

Then I want to receive from that hardware bytes too. Imagine that someone change the color of that light, I want to know it. So I created a receiving method:

```
public static String readByte() throws IOException{
    InputStream input;
    DataInputStream iData;
    String data = null;
    try {

        byte[] bytes = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        Socket server = new Socket(2000);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        input = client.getInputStream();
        iData = new DataInputStream(input);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(iData);
        iData.skip(0);
        iData.read(bytes, 0, 8);
        data = bytesToHex(bytes); //A simple method that change bytes to hex, this method it's correct
        Log.w("READ", "" + data);
        input.close();
        client.close();
        server.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.w("EROR","No es pot conectar");

    }
    return data;

}
```

Here I create a server that connects to client to get data (I don't know if it's necessary to create a server). The problem is that I always receive 7 bytes, and they are always the same, I used skip(7) to skip the protocol bytes, but then I don't receive anymore bytes.

I know that the hardware send bytes through the wifi where I'm connected, but I can't catch them.

**_________TO SUM UP_________**

I think the problem is that I can't catch the bytes because the hardware part simply send me, and my Android app can't store it. I would like to read the byte just when hardware sends me it, or something like this. I searched methods everywhere and object attributes and I can't find a solution to this :(

Thanks for your attention. 
Wanted to know to if ServerSocket is strictly necessary or not.

Comment: Are you sure that the same 2000 port should be used for communication in both directions? both to and from the wifi access point?

Comment: Ideally, your application should start a ServerSocket on some port.  Whenever there is a change in light color, the hardware should contact your ServerSocket.  But, I do not think you have the facility of telling wifi access point to send data to some server socket.

Comment: **Wanted to know to if ServerSocket is strictly necessary or not.** You need a ServerSocket in the Android Device, if it shall accept a connection from the hardware. Do you have to use TCP? This smells like better using UDP to me ...

Comment: This Access Point only send and receive data though the port 2000.
Any way, is there any way to catch byte sent from hardware through wifi just in the moment when it sends the byte?

Comment: But I can send bytes with no problem with TCP, there have to be a way to receive it too, no?

Comment: You can receive on the same connection. But you'll have to keep it up. That means you will have to use a seperate thread for reading (on one and the same Socket instance) or use nio.

Comment: I use different methods, it's not sufficient enough? I thought thread can only start one time, and I need to do this several times.

Comment: Then I create socket and input + outputs out from the methods?

Comment: The point is, you cannot know when the Hardware sends data. So you have to have a thread (and a _loop_ within it ) keep checking for incoming data. You can share the same socket instance across threads to send to the Hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When java program sends data to hardware, at that time, java program is the client and hardware is the server.

When the hardware sends data to java program, the hardware is the client and your java program is the server.

So, in your java program, you need to have two threads, one client thread (with a Socket to send bytes) and a server thread (with a ServerSocket, lets say for example, on port 8999) to receive bytes.

For the hardware to send you the bytes, it needs the following details.
1. IP Address or host name of the device on which your java program runs.
2. The port in which the ServerSocket is listening (8999 in our case).

If your hardware manual says it can send data to you, then, I am sure you can configure these details somewhere. (I am not sure what your hardware is. So, look at your hardware manual about how to configure these details).

Sometimes, the device can send response on the same Socket you opened. (Again, I am at a loss how it is done in your hardware. Refer your hardware manual).  In such case, keep your socket open and read from it in a separate thread.

Comment: It has to be strictly threads?  I want to do it several times, and in case of threads, I will start it many times, is it viable?
Do you know where I can find sample code of what are you saying? I'm a noob with Threads :( Sorry.

Comment: No, you won't start several threads. You'll have one "main" thread and a Reader thread that will be in a loop checking for incoming data (read) as long as the connection is up.

Comment: But i'm receiving same bytes all the time: 2A 48 45 4C 4C 4F 2A and if I put the input in a infinite bucle, it reads the same all time, even if the light changes and the hardware sends a byte to me.

Comment: @Llangostu I feel that you should be connecting to some different port.  Can you please check if you are connecting to the correct port number for getting events from the access point?

Comment: @vivek_ganesan Yes, I'm in the right port cause sending bytes don't give me any problem, when I configure Access Point I put the IP 1.2.3.4 and port 2000. Port can't be wrong. The problem is maybe I use the same port to receive data? But I think Access Point cant only send and receive in one unique port. At least this one.

Comment: @Llangostu is there any publicly available document link available for this configuration of access point? may be i can take a look at it.

Comment: Wait a second ... Port 2000 is Cisco Skinny Call Control Protocol ... Does your config interfere with some functionality on the router? Have tried some other port?

Comment: @Vivek_ganesan it's a native hardware of company where I work :S I only know that trough wifi AP, there are relays sending bytes to both directions (to hardware or to my device trough a wifi access point), obviously I have to be connected to that wireless network to send and receive bytes from it. Thanks for your interest, but I think that the problem it's me.
Fildor, I changed the port of Access Point and the port of my app, it happens the same.
I think the problem is that I have to read just in the exactly moment when it sends me the byte,or I don't know. To many hours spent on this... u.u

Comment: @Llangostu Are you trying to communicate to access point or to some other hardware?

Comment: @Llangostu coming to your point of having to read "just when the hardware sends the bytes", you need to listen "all the time" and you need to use the "same" Socket instance.  Only doing all the above will make sure you read the data as and when the hardware sends you the bytes.

Comment: @vivek_ganesan i'm sending it to acces point, then the acces point send it to the hardware, anyway I will try what you are saying. Just finished working this week so I will try it in 2 days cause I not have the code here. If it works I will put your answer as valid. Thank you very much :) Thank Fildor too :)